# Regex or Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to grab the width2 and height2.

```
// JScript File
// JScript File
iframeW = parseInt(width) + 10;
iframeH = parseInt(height) + 10;

width2 = parseInt(width) + -9 ;
height2 = parseInt(height) + 2;

document.write('<ifr'+'ame width='+iframeW+' height='+iframeH+' scrolling=no frameborder=0 scrolling=no allowtransparency=true src=http://zzzz.zzzz-zzzzzz.com/embed.php?id='+file+'&width='+width2+'&height='+height2+'&key2=1114></ifr'+'ame>');
```

Originally `width=600` and `height=400` when it runs in the browser. It comes out as `width=591` and `height=402`. The problem is it almost changes daily.

```
http://zzzz.zzzz-zzzz.com/embed.php?id=channel1&width=591&height=402&key2=1114
```

and so it messes up my regex, since it keeps changing the width and height. Anyway how I can grab this automatically with either regex or python.

Sorry, newb at this...slow learning process :(

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do this with Python. Regex and Python are not valid comparisons - the latter is a programming language, the former is implemented with a finite state machine that virtually any language can reproduce (think of the difference between a language and an algorithm). Python has a module dedicated to using regular expressions. So does Javascript.

Comment: Attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions [leads to madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/1732454#1732454).  Your language of choice, whatever it is, already has at least one library _specifically_ for parsing HTML.  Use it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a regex, you could try:

`&width=(\d+)` for the width and `&height=(\d+)` for the height. Both of these will return one to unlimited digits following "&width=" or "&height=" in the first capture group

regex101.com is a good tool for building regexes. You can enter the regex you're thinking of and it puts out a nice explanation of what is actually happening

Comment: For hight i can Regex the +2, like Height=40$doregex[height2] and it will give me the right height since it goes 400 + 2 = 402.

Comment: @SXhaferaj You can use parseint(string) to get the value as an integer type, then you can do anything you want with it